# Copy previous line when the condition is met [Python]

Tags: python

I am trying to print previous line when the condition is met.
Example: `abc.txt` file contains below lines

```
User 1 - I like eating Apple
User 2 - I like eating Apple
User 3 - I like eating Apple
User 4 - I like eating Grapes
User 5 - I like eating Apple
User 6 - I like eating Orange
```

If I did not find "Apple" text in the line, then I need to print previous line "User 3 - I like eating Apple" and "User 5 - I like eating Apple".

What I have tried:

```
with open('abc.txt', 'r') as f:        
    for line in f:
        prev_line = line[:-1]
        try:
            if "Apple" not in line:
                print(prev_line)
                continue
        except StopIteration:
            pass
```

**Actual output:**

```
User 4 - I like eating Grapes
User 6 - I like eating Orange
```

**Expected Output:**

```
User 3 - I like eating Apple
User 5 - I like eating Apple
```

Answer (score 2):

`line[:-1]` gives you the content of the *current* line, up to the second-to-last char. It doesn't give you the previous line.

You can read all lines using:

```py
with open('C:\\Users\\chaitr2x\\Desktop\\abc.txt', 'r') as f: 
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Then you can do something like this:

```py
for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
    if "Apple" not in line:
        print(lines[idx -1])
```

Comment: I suggest adding exception handling for when the 0th line does not contain "Apple"; or iterate over `lines[1:]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`line[:-1]` does not point to the previous line. You need to maintain the state of the previous line like this:

```
# change the value here in case Apple is not in the first line
prev_line = ""
for line in f:
    try:
        if "Apple" not in line:
            print(prev_line)
            continue
        prev_line = line
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```